# Recommended patterns to consume an asynchronous microservice from a client?

Tags: asynchronous, microservices

so our use case is to have a microservice which is very expensive (takes time to run). this service is consumed by any client.

i've read about some patterns for best practices for consuming, for example:

1. use WebSockets - which will make the server able to send the result back to the client.
2. Constant polling (i don't like it much)
3. Leases - it's some kind of polling - the client will acquire a lease for X minutes, and will renew it every few minutes until a response comes - but if the response comes back, the client will still have to wait for it (although the result is ready already) - this will make cleanup easier (clients which abandoned the requests)

i'd love to hear about your best practices in this event-driven microservices architecture

thanks!

Comment: Is the client you're mentioning also a microservice?

Comment: @WillC nope, though it can be.   i saw that commonly leases with polling is used though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need a pubsub framework/product, e.g. ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ, ZeroMQ (NetMQ) or maybe even Redis pubsub/queues

Comment: the thing that interests me - how do you publish a topic to a "client"? the client usually needs to poll if any topic is directed to him - unless a constant connection is kept.

Comment: The client can create his own topic at runtime and when making a request to the service can include the topic as the     return address. The service processes the request and publishes the response when complete. No polling involved. All async.  With pubsub and queues there are many ways to achieve async communication

Comment: the question is, what's that return address? will the server need to connect to that might be suspicious address and send data there?
you also now make the clients to support getting responses through a URL They provide - i'm not sure if its best practice...

Comment: The return address is a topic name, e.g. client:123.  It's not a URL or IP address. The underlying assumption is that both clients and services have an open socket with each other or more likely a common message broker service

Comment: Read this: https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2015-05-18-part1-rabbitmq-for-beginners-what-is-rabbitmq.html

Comment: @simpsojo I think there is also one requirement where this falls short and its the case where the client could be a UI client (@ArielB, please correct me if I'm wrong but in your question you mentioned "any client" which in that case can also be a UI client). In that effect, it seems that WebSockets solution may be the best of both worlds.

Comment: Who knows, it's all very general. It could indeed be a mixture with pubsub internally and websockets for internet facing clients.  Intranet based UI clients could connect directly to a message broker/server process.

Comment: Yep i understand that, thanks for the clarification :) i still don't like the fact that each client must keep an open connection, now the client has to understand what's a "web socket", instead of only URL, no?
internal pub/sub does make sense though.
so i think both solutions are acceptable (pub/sub VS polling with leases), and there's no 3rd that i can think of :)

Comment: Polling works at a lower level compared to a framework that takes care of connection reliability (e.g. reconnect on intermitent network issues) and message reliability (guarantees re: receive only once, error  cases).

Comment: Great, interesting talk. Thank you.